# Как сделать, чтобы перемножались 3 последовательных числа?

Tags: python, list

Есть список [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]:

Нужно, чтобы перемножались 3 последовательных числа таким образом:

```
1 * 3 * 5
3 * 5 * 7
5 * 7 * 9
```

Я попробовал так, но при запуске ничего не выводится:

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    
i = -1
num = 0
    
while i > 5:
    i += 1
    num = list1[i] * list[i+1] * list[i+2]
    print(num)
```

Comment: `for a,b,c in zip(list1[:-2], list1[1:-1], list1[2:]):
    print(a*b*c)
`

Comment: `i = -1; while i > 5: ...` ...

Comment: @splash58 Можно сократить: `for a, b, c in zip(list1, list1[1:], list1[2:]): print(a * b * c)`. Ведь `zip()` работает, пока во всех итерируемых есть значения, а в `list1[2:]` на 2 элемента меньше, чем в `list1`. Соответственно, как только закончится `list1[2:]`, `zip()` прекратит работу.

Comment: @MiniMax Согласен )

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что у вас там "не производится", но вот так - работает (при любой длинне списка, кстати):

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] 
i = 0
num = 0 
while i < (len(list1)-2): 
    num = list1[i] * list1[i+1] * list1[i+2]
    i += 1 
    print(num)
```

Результат:

```
15
105
315
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for a,b,c in zip(list1[:-2], list1[1:-1], list1[2:]):     
    print(a*b*c)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ?

Comment: ответ, состоящий лишь из фрагмента кода, движок помещает в очередь сообщений низкого качества. я думаю, не напрасно. хороший ответ всё-таки должен содержать пояснения: например, что именно у автора вопроса «неправильно» и как именно это можно исправить.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ну ответь общий, так что пусть истинный автор(splash58) или еще кто-нибудь правят.

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким образом, вроде, работает.

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

for i in range(len(list1) - 2): 
    list2 = (list1[i:i+3])
    print(list2[0] * list2[1] * list2[2])
```